# ical4j 1.0.6 Unparseable date exception thrown

Tags: java, grails, ical4j

I'm using ical4j 1.0.6 in a project, and have encountered an issue in an events feed that I can't figure out. The exemplar VEVENT appears below in a stripped down version of its ical, sanitized to remove client data. The DTSTART attribute of the VEVENT throws an Unparseable date exception.

Any ideas from the other folks who are more familiar with the source (I've just really started looking at the source today -- never had a reason before, since ical4j works so well). The DTSTART attributes in the VTIMEZONE parse just fine, but not that in the VEVENT.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Date iCal v3.3//NONSGML kigkonsult.se iCalcreator 2.16.12//
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT:Upcoming Events
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Chicago
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20151101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0600
TZNAME:CST
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20150308T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:CDT
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:calendar.uid.1
DTSTAMP:20141210T150412Z
CREATED:20140930T161212Z
DESCRIPTION:Body: Some descriptive text 
DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20141212T180000
DTEND;TZID=America/Chicago:20141212T180000
LAST-MODIFIED:20140930T161212Z
SUMMARY:The summary line
URL;TYPE=URI:http://www.someserver.com/events/the_summary_line
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```